# Decoding Shellcode from MSFvenom(xor x64)?

Tags: 64-bit, decode, xor, shellcode, metasploit

[Encoding the shellcode three times using the x64 xor Encoder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiCT1.png)

I'm writing my own exploit and I've wondered if I need to decode the shellcode when adding it in my program or is the decoder stub inside of the shellcode already? If I need to decode, how can I do that, there is no key given?

Comment: The 40 byte increment in every iteration probably points to stub that will decrypt the next itreration's payload. If you paste the shellcode I can help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You don't have to decrypt the shellcode. I ran the same command and got something which looked like this

```
   0:    48 31 c9                 xor    rcx, rcx
   3:    48 81 e9 b6 ff ff ff     sub    rcx, 0xffffffffffffffb6
   a:    48 8d 05 ef ff ff ff     lea    rax, [rip+0xffffffffffffffef]        # 0x0
  11:    48 bb af cc c5 c0 90     movabs rbx, 0x29153c90c0c5ccaf
  18:    3c 15 29  
  1b:    48 31 58 27              xor    QWORD PTR [rax+0x27], rbx
  1f:    48 2d f8 ff ff ff        sub    rax, 0xfffffffffffffff8
  25:    e2 f4                    loop   0x1b
```

This was the starting part of shellcode followed by xor'd 2nd iteration payload. On decrypting I saw that It had a similar stub attached. So you don't have to decrypt. Just point execution to the start of the buffer.

Comment: Yes, I injected the shellcode into the memory and ran it, it worked without decoding. The decoder stub is already inside of the shellcode, thats why it gets bigger with every iteration. Thanks for your help